# multiple choice question on group of matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the set of matrices $$G=\left\{ \left( \begin{array}{ll}s&b\\0&1 \end{array}\right) b \in \mathbb{Z}, s \in \{1,-1\} \right\}.$$Then which of the following are true

1. G forms a group under addition
2. G forms an abelian group under multiplication
3. Every element of G is diagonolizable over $\mathbb{C}$
4. G is finitely generated group under multiplication

I am getting
1) is false since not closed under addition
2)Forms a group under multiplication (  abelian or not i don't know)
3)Not true if $a=1$
4) dont know
please help me to complete

Comment: A few examples with $s=1$ in one matrix, $s=-1$ in the other, should convince you that $G$ isn't abelian.

Comment: So answer will be finitely generate right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- $1$ is false:

  Your approach is correct. Since, for example, $\begin{pmatrix}1&*\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}1&*\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2&*\\*&* \end{pmatrix} \notin G$
- $2$ is false:

  Take $b \neq 0$.$$\begin{pmatrix}1&b\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1&b\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-1&2b\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$ whereas $$\begin{pmatrix}-1&b\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&b\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-1&\color{red}{0}\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$
- $3$ is false too:

  Since, for example, $\begin{pmatrix}1&b\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}$ is not diagonalizable when $b \neq 0$
- $4$ is true

  The finite set $$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\0&1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$$ generates $G$(verify!)

Comment: Is it generated by 2 elements ? I am not clear about generating set

Comment: @sabeelmsk: See my edit